# Will ubuntu 14.04 LTS work on Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3 motherboard

Tags: 14.04, compatibility

Building a computer with midrange specs.  But I need to know if Ubuntu will run on a Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3 motherboard.  Will I need drivers etc?

Comment: In short, it should work.  But if you encounter any problems, we're here to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3 with an Intel processor i5-4670 . 
Nearly all things are working fine; most without installing additional drivers. Installation was very easy. Even I installed Ubuntu on a bootable external USB-drive, to try it with several Computers. It works.

Internet, drives, CD/DVD, Audio, Video, usb, SATA, ... : no problems.
For my printer (HP officejet pro 8600) I installed the HPLIP Toolbox, included in Ubuntu's "software center", and it works fine.

Only my scanner (Epson perfection 4490) does not work until now; though I had installed the driver packages offered by Epson and made recommended corrections in epson* files. But on other computer the scanner works with the same ubuntu (for that the external installation). Today I asked Gigabyte support. Perhaps they will give me a satisfactory answer.

### Of course, if you have other components, you will have more or less problems.

2 new remarks:
1. I forgot to say, that I use the Gigabyte Mainboard only in BIOS (MBR) mode, not in UEFI mode: In BIOS menu - BIOS Features - I set all Points which has a EFI choice to legacy or only legacy. With UEFI activated I got much more problems - in Linux and in Windows.
2. Today I got this answer from Gigabyte: "Da wir Linux und CO nicht testen / Supporten, können wir da leider nicht helfen. Wenn unter Windows 7 / 8 oder Win8.1 nicht auftritt, ist alles OK." This is of course very very unsatisfactory. In other words: if you have any problems with Linux on Gigabyte Mainboard, you will be left alone.